# Event Goal Conversion

Tags: pdf, google-analytics

I wonder if someone can help me with getting my PDF download event to show up as a conversion? I have read other posts on here and also asked on the Google forum but so far I haven't managed to get it going. Please note, I am using the new, universal tracking code.

What I have done so far:

- Set up in Google Tag Manager event tracking - this works perfectly and is recording in GA.
- I have added the code to the PDF link that I am trying to track anchor text
- Set up Goal in GA with event type set to Event with the fields set to 'equal to', except for value which is marked 'greater than'. Category - PDF, Action - Download, Label - Brochure, Value - 250.

What am I doing wrong? Nothing comes up when I verify this goal and nothing comes up in real time conversion tracking.

Thanks in advance.

Jack

Comment: Is the value greater than 250 ? And is it relevant to your goal conversions (you do not need to fill in all fields, if you just want to record downloads regardless it would be enought to set the category field to PDF).

Answer (score 0):

You might have an error with your Google Analytics event configuration. Try this:

1. Remove the goal Value in the Goal Details (Event Conditions)
2. Change to NO "Use the Event value as the Goal value for the
   conversion"
3. Set the value yourself (e.g. 5$)
4. Make your to remove the value from the GA javascript or Tag in GTM

[image]